# Can I add Apostrophe to numbers I get in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have a Query that gives me a list of numbers, for example:

```
61728_0be80d3c-029d-4d06-ae75-37f72fdeacaf
61784_4e1b2b79-1190-4e65-91cc-07552e28b522
61864_f0a58134-a1d5-40f6-ada1-d12b7e991675
61928_3a5a70b1-9350-4acf-99e4-e858f14a6d98
62048_a489f752-ae51-4919-b720-1b6e15235a3e
62112_3a8289e9-c5e6-4aae-8c8a-431cc5ca9415
62176_95fbfdc9-88e3-4918-ac19-6b54f3205af4
62296_2f6fbd6b-9af4-4d6c-85e8-07ba64326669
62688_71c3ee51-0f5c-4f8e-8026-8b90a335795e
62776_e93d9f1d-272f-4161-80eb-5de90a026829
```

How can I make this query give me all these numbers in agg_string in order to add the to a where clause, so I can filter answers in a different query to only these numbers.
example:

```
'61728_0be80d3c-029d-4d06-ae75-37f72fdeacaf','61784_4e1b2b79-1190-4e65-91cc-07552e28b522',
'61864_f0a58134-a1d5-40f6-ada1-d12b7e991675' etc
```

in order to put it inside of:

```
where XXX IN ('61728_0be80d3c-029d-4d06-ae75-37f72fdeacaf','61784_4e1b2b79-1190-4e65-91cc-07552e28b522','61864_f0a58134-a1d5-40f6-ada1-d12b7e991675')
```

Any way to do it auto in sql or excel if not?

tried to use `string_agg("personId",',')` and it will add the commas between the numbers but i cant add Apostrophe at the beginning of the personID and at the end

Comment: SQL allows to join several tables or even create subqueries. I'm positively sure you don't need to complicate your life this way.

Answer (score 2):

You can concatenate single quotes to the ID inside the string_agg()

```
string_agg(concat('''', "personId", ''''), ',')
```

or a bit simpler:

```
string_agg(quote_literal("personId"), ',')
```

---

If those IDs are the result of a query, then you can also use it directly:

```
where xxx in (select "personId" from ...)
```